# WFPSampler Compilation issue - wfpcalloutsclassreg not found

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, wdk, wfp

The compilation of the Microsoft demo [WFPSampler](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/trans/WFPSampler) Project fails in any setup (32/64 - debug/release) on [WFPSamplerCalloutDriver.InX](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/network/trans/WFPSampler/sys/WFPSamplerCalloutDriver.InX) at line 36 :

```
[ClassInstall32.nt$ARCH$]
   AddReg = WFPCalloutsClassReg
```

:

```
Stamping .\WFPSamplerCalloutDriver.inf [Version] section with DriverVer=06/29/2017,19.37.54.422
sys\WFPSamplerCalloutDriver.inx(36-36): error 1203: Section [wfpcalloutsclassreg] not found.
sys\WFPSamplerCalloutDriver.inx(49-49): warning 2083: Section [defaultuninstall.ntx86] not referenced or used.
sys\WFPSamplerCalloutDriver.inx(53-53): warning 2083: Section [defaultuninstall.ntx86.services] not referenced or used.
sys\WFPSamplerCalloutDriver.inx(56-56): warning 2083: Section [wfpcalloutclassreg] not referenced or used.
sys\WFPSamplerCalloutDriver.inx(66-66): warning 2083: Section [wfpsamplercalloutdriver.nt.coinstallers] not referenced or used.
sys\WFPSamplerCalloutDriver.inx(70-70): warning 2083: Section [wfpsamplercalloutdriver.coinstaller.addreg] not referenced or used.
sys\WFPSamplerCalloutDriver.inx(73-73): warning 2083: Section [wfpsamplercalloutdriver.coinstaller.copyfiles] not referenced or used.
```

The setup is using Visual Studio Community, SDK and WDK installed following this [page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit) downloads and the build procedure were followed from the [ReadMe file](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/network/trans/WFPSampler/README.md)

Couldn't find any relevant information about this issue.

I've uninstalled and reinstall VS, SDK and WDK to the latest version and it did not solve the issue.

Current setup is

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.02053
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   7.0.20622.1
Common Azure Tools   1.8
Debugging Tools for Windows   10.0.15063.0
JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Project System   2.0
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
NuGet Package Manager   3.4.4
PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
TypeScript   1.8.36.0
Windows Driver Kit   10.0.15063.0
```

Comment: Try changing line 56 from `[WFPCalloutClassReg]` to `[WFPCalloutsClassReg]` (note the 's').

Comment: As simple as that, thanks cynic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in the sample. The relevant section is called
`WFPCalloutClassReg` (line 56) but is referred to as `WFPCalloutsClassReg` elsewhere in the file (note the extra 's'). So the fix is to change line 56 to `[WFPCalloutsClassReg]`.

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10 (SDK 10.0.22000.0) The solution above is not enough anymore.

Changes needed:

- changes mentioned in https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/pull/538
- Add SHA256 to Sys → WFPSamplerCalloutDriver → Driver Signing → General → file digest algo